Fluid flow through a pipe system with diffuser
I'm brand new to this platform, hope I'm right here. I'm calculating big pipe networks (open systems) with fans using the Hardy Cross method. In this method, I have to sum up all the pressure losses. In the open systems I have to consider height and velocity changes, too. Otherwise the Bernoulli equation is not satisfied. Everything except the diffuser works - except the diffuser, to refine my problem, I made a very easy system.

When I apply Bernoulli here, I get the following:

However, if I assume for the Resistances R1,2=0.15 kg/m^7, the areas A1=1 m^2, A2=2 m^2 and the pressures p1=10 Pa, p2=0 Pa, I get a negative value for the volume flow rate Q.
What does that mean? Thank you!

If you get a negative value for $Q^2$ (not $Q$) then it means that there is no real value of $Q$ that satisfies the Bernoulli equation for the assumptions you've made.  This means that you have made an error in your assumptions or your model, and you need to re-examine your setup to figure out what that error is.
